# How to a background task only once after App installation

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager

**Problem :**
I have a scenario where I need to upload some data to the server in the first launch of the app. And the upload task should be done even if user quits the App immediately. This task need not to be done always, but only for the very first time during App launch.

**What I have tried:**

I'm currently using a Service for this purpose. I'm launching sticky service  during App launch and does the job in Service. So, even if user quits the App immediately, my service will be restarting and I will retry the upload process.

But here, I need to keep a boolean flag in the shared preference `hasUploadDone` to remember the upload process is already done or not, and I need to check this during every app launch though it is not required most of the times.
I don't see it as a nice approach. Is there any better way to handle this scenario apart from this service - boolean flag combination? can it be achieved using Work-manager or something in a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Preferences for this:

In your MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor.putBoolean("previouslyStarted", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then In your onCreate method
If your app was started before Shared preferences will save value "true" for "previouslySaved" else it will default "false"

```
SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
previouslyStarted = saved_values.getBoolean("previouslyStarted", false);
```

Use if else to check if your application is stated for the first time

```
if (previouslyStarted) {
    //App has been started previously.
}
else {
   //App started for the first time.
   //Upload your data here.
}
```

Comment: I think you did't read the question properly!! Whatever you have suggested is what I have done currently.  I'm asking for any better solution. Please read the question fully.